# How can I mount a volume to docker container in OSX?

Tags: php, macos, apache, docker

My ultimate goal is to run different versions of PHP on my local computer for testing.

I believe Docker is the best way to accomplish this.

I have been able to get a container with Apache and PHP running via this tutorial: https://github.com/tutumcloud/apache-php

But the issue is that I cannot mount a volume so that I can edit local files and view them on the docker container.

Here are my steps in terminal running in the same directory as the docker file:

1. `docker build -t tutum/apache-php .`
2. `docker run -d -p 8080:80 tutum/apache-php -v /Users/user-name-here/apache-php/sample:/app/`

The error I get back is:

> docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"-v\": executable file not found in $PATH".

I'm on OSX - El Captain, just installed latest version of Docker and Docker tools.

Comment: Absolute life saver. Banged my head for hours. Can you reply with this as the answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic format of the `docker run` command is:

```
docker run [<options>] <image> [<command>]
```

In this case, your image is `tutum/apache-php`, and the run command is being parsed like this:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 tutum/apache-php -v /Users/user-name-here/apache-php/sample:/app/

docker run
    options: -d -p 8080:80
      image: tutum/apache-php
    command: -v /Users/user-name-here/apache-php/sample:/app/
```

This is the source of your error.

> exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH

Since the command begins with `-v`, it will try to locate and execute that command. Of course, it doesn't exist, so you will get this error.

The fix is simply to move the `-v` option and its argument to the proper place.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v /Users/user-name-here/apache-php/sample:/app/ tutum/apache-php
```